# Trying to use cython to pass a list from a python script to a C++ function, causes segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm trying to use Cython to pass an array from a Python script into a C++ function, modify it, then return the array from the Python script. I know that passing arrays using Cython is a challenge, and I'm wondering if it is clear to anyone where I have gone wrong in my implementation. I've included my .h, .cpp, .pxd, and .pyx files below.

.h

```
#ifndef DUMMY_PROPAGATOR_H
#define DUMMY_PROPAGATOR_H

namespace dummy_namespace {
    class dummy_class {
        public:
            double t;
            std::vector<double> state;
            double physicalProperties;
            double forces;
            dummy_class();
            dummy_class(double t, std::vector<double> state, double physicalProperties, double forces);
            ~dummy_class();
            std::vector<double> prop_to(std::vector<double> state);
    };
}

#endif //DUMMY_PROPAGATOR_H
```

.cpp:

```
#include "dummy_prop.h"
#include <vector>

namespace dummy_namespace {

    dummy_class::dummy_class() {}

    dummy_class::dummy_class(double t, std::vector<double> state, double physicalProperties, double forces) {
        this->t = t;
        this->state = {};
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            this->state[i] = state[i];
        }
        this->physicalProperties = physicalProperties;
        this->forces = forces;
    }

    dummy_class::~dummy_class() {}

    std::vector<double> dummy_class::prop_to(std::vector<double> state) {
        std::vector<double> new_state = {};
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            new_state[i] = state[i];
        }
        return new_state;
    }
}
```

.pxd

```
from cpython cimport array
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cimport cython

cdef extern from "dummy_prop/dummy_prop.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "dummy_prop/dummy_prop.h" namespace "dummy_namespace":
    cdef cppclass dummy_class:
        dummy_class() except +
        dummy_class(double, vector[double], double, double) except +
        double t
        double physicalProperties 
        double forces
        vector[double] state
        vector[double] prop_to(vector[double]) except +
```

.pyx:

```
# distutils: language = c++

from dummy_prop cimport dummy_class
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cimport cython

cdef class prop_state:
    cdef dummy_class c_instance  # Hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping

    def __cinit__(self, double t, vector[double] state, double physicalProperties, double forces):
        self.c_instance = dummy_class(t, state, physicalProperties, forces)

    def get_prop_state(self, vector[double] state):
        cdef vector[double] new_state = self.c_instance.prop_to(state)
        return new_state
```

Comment: The title says list, the text, array.  They aren't the same thing, unless the dtype is object.

Comment: `this->state = {};` creates a zero length vector. You then try to write 14 elements into it

Comment: The question I've linked is basically the same issue. It's a really elementary c++ issue and has nothing to do with Cython or any of the other complications you've added